# To append conference in google calendar's create event popup on click of button from 3rd party video conference plugin

Tags: google-apps-script, plugins, google-calendar-api

Currently with my 3rd party video conferencing plugin, When user clicks on Google calendar there is popup for scheduling event and in that they can select custom video conference plugin that they want to use from drop-down.

I need to achieve functionality in that, when user clicks on google calendar and popup shows up for scheduling event at that time i have a button in plugin says "Add Meeting". On  click of that button, 3rd party conference should be added automatically in event popup. So, user don't need to select conference from drop down This functionality already working in zoom google calendar

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you can make a feature request to the third party that created the plugin

Answer (score 0):

In this case you would need to use the Google Calendar API. The [Insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert) or [Update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/update) method would be needed depending if you are either creating or updating an event.

When doing the request you need to make sure to fill the information related to ["Conference data"](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#:%7E:text=writable-,conferenceData,-.conferenceId). The conferenceData.conferenceId value will change the video conferencing information from the calendar event according to your needs.

Comment: Hello, Tried with google calendar insert event, But it actually creates event with conference data on calendar, In my case i need to append conference data in event creation popup of calendar when click made from plugin. Thanks

Comment: @DhavalParmar in this case I think having a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help ups get the idea of what you are doing and trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by using ConferenceDataService builder.I'm calling an action which calls a new function when click made on "Add-meeting" from 3rd party plugin. in that function,new entry points created for phoneEntryPoint and videoEntryPoint which added to the newConferenceDataBuilder object from ConferenceDataService. Lastly return that conference-data through newCalendarEventActionResponseBuilder.

Here is the link for reference:-
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/calendar/calendar-actions#setting_conference_data_with_a_callback_function

```
      var phoneEntryPoint = ConferenceDataService.newEntryPoint()
        .setEntryPointType(ConferenceDataService.EntryPointType.PHONE)
        .setUri("tel:" + "91XXXXXX");

      var videoEntryPoint = ConferenceDataService.newEntryPoint()
      .setEntryPointType(ConferenceDataService.EntryPointType.VIDEO)
      .setUri("videourl")
      .setMeetingCode("meetingid");


     var conferenceData = 
        ConferenceDataService.newConferenceDataBuilder()
       .addEntryPoint(phoneEntryPoint)
       .addEntryPoint(videoEntryPoint)
       .setConferenceSolutionId("1")
       .build();

     return CardService.newCalendarEventActionResponseBuilder()
          .setConferenceData(conferenceData)
          .build();
```